# Given a string, write a program that counts the number of words that begin and end with the same letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example: 'Two trout eat toast' would return the number 2 (trout, toast)

Here's my code so far. What would be the best way to do this program?

```
string = input("Enter a string ")

words = string.split()

number = 0

if (word[0].lower() == word[len(word)-1].lower()):
number += 1

print(number)
```

Comment: What is the problem with what your wrote (other than that when you pasted it here you didn't preserve indentation, and that you are likely missing a `for` loop)?

Comment: `word[len(word)-1]` can be replaced with `word[-1]`

Comment: I think your code is missing a for loop or something, where does `word` come from?

Answer (score 4):

You're pretty close to what you want. You need to iterate over `words` to test each word:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")
words = string.split()

number = 0
# iterate over `words` to test each word.
for word in words:
    # word[len(word)-1] can be replaced with just word[-1].
    if (word[0].lower() == word[-1].lower()):
        number += 1
print(number)
```

Running the above program with your given example produces the result:

```
Enter a string:  Two trout eat toast
2
```

Perhaps a cleaner way to do the above would be to lowercase the input string before iterating over it and using `sum`:

```
words = input("Enter a string: ").lower().split()
number = sum(word[0] == word[-1] for word in words) 
print(number) # 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was close, just wasn't too sure if there was a cleaner way.

Comment: @codeintech3 Yeah, you could use `sum`. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a one-liner:

```
print(sum([1 for word in input("Enter a string").lower().split() if word[0] == word[-1]]))
```

Comment: `.lower().split()`

Comment: Good eye.  This also doesn't take punctuation into account, but neither does the posters answer

Comment: The OP does account for case in his original code, so I didn't think it should be lost. Good point about punctuation.

Comment: Yes you're right. I meant punctuation isn't mentioned.  Case is definitely present and important

Comment: Square brackets for the sum aren't necessary, btw

Answer (score 0):

```
b = a.split()                                                                                              
c = 0                                                                                                          
for item in b:                                                                                                    
    if item[0] == item[-1]:                                                                                       
        c+=1 
print(c)
```

Comment: Those are horrible variable names. It would be better to use the OP's names or improve upon them. Particularly bad is naming a string `i` as most readers will assume it is an integer.

Comment: thnxx @Steven Rumbalsk

Comment: @cricket_007 first it split the string, and we get a list of words then loop through the list and check each element first and the last character if both are equal increment the counter variable and in last print the value of counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple breakdown one...

```
s = 'i love you Dad'
    l =[]
    l = s.split(' ')
    count = 0
    for i in l:
        if len(i)==1:
            print(i)
        else:
            if i[0].upper()==i[len(i)-1].upper():
                count = count+1
                print(i)
print(count)
Output: i
Dad
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
example = "Two trout eat toast"
example = (example.lower()).split()

count = 0
for i in example:
    i = list(i)
    if i[0] == i[-1]:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Just taking the `example` string, make it `lower.()` for comparisons, then split it and you will have the `words`.

After you turn each `word` into a `list` and compare the beginning and end of that `list`